# How to Search an Array for a String input by a user in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of 5 strings.  My Javascript file is linked to a HTML file in order to retrieve a string from a user.  If the string the user enters matches 1 of the 5 items in my array then it returns "Well done" or something of the sorts.

I need to know how I search the array for the string I have taken in from the user.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could use `.indexOf`:

```
var strings = ["hello", "world", "foo", "bar"];
function existsInStrings(str) {
    return strings.indexOf(str) !== -1;
}
console.log(existsInStrings("hello")); //true
console.log(existsInStrings("there")); //false
```